# Executing multiple javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to execute 3 different navigateToUrl(); functions from the Chrome console at once, but have the second and third functions activate AFTER the new page loads. Ie. After the first function executes, I need to let the new page load before executing the second function, and let that page load before executing the third function.

Is there a way to do this with one function, or do I have to run them separately after each page loads?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: Each new URL is appending something specific from the new page to the current URL

Comment: What do you mean new page load? As in refreshing the current page? or an entirely new page loads?

Comment: Let the new page load that the navigateToUrl() function pulls up.

Comment: you need three functions because refreshing will make it forget about un-run ones.